# How to setup HTTPS to custom port (3000 in my case) on EC2 instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, port

I've developed a simple **Node.js/Socket.Io** server running on **EC2** instance on port 3000.

There is a load balancer setup for that instance and an elastic IP pointing to it too.

However I've added the TCP port 3000 to the port configuration of the load balancer (in Listeners, where I have the HTTPS already setup for port 443, and I tried to do the same for port 3000 using the secure tcp protocol) as well as to the security groups of the instance (with source 0.0.0.0/0).

However when I try to reach https://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000
I get the following error:

> An error occurred during a connection to
>   ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000. SSL received a
>   record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code:
>   SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

(same happens when I try the **Elastic IP** or the Load Balancer host name).

Can you tell me what else I should do in order to allow HTTPS connections to port 3000?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: What's the output of `openssl s_client -connect ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000`?

Comment: This is the answer: 
CONNECTED(00000003)
28428:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.8.4/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:618:

But that is when I use the elastic IP pointing to the instance itself.

Comment: If I use the ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com it returns this: 
gethostbyname failure
connect:errno=2

Comment: Right, the `SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol` means that your server isn't returning a certificate on that port. Why not is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: Well, we have apache running on port 80 there and we access it via HTTPS. So how I can make it work on port 3000 too? (there is a different server on port 3000 /node.js/)?

Comment: Did you ever have any more luck with this one?

Answer (score 0):

1)) Let's assume your public ip is  54.74.67.112.

1A)) Export the port 3000 in the security group.

1B))In the address bar of your browser use:
54.74.67.112:3000 .

2)) To use the AWS DNS, as you basically are doing, these are the steps.

2A)) In the security group you have to expose the port 80, not 3000.
So, In the address bar of your browser use:
https://ec2-54-74-67-112.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

2B)) Inside the EC2 shell, you have to run your node application on the port 80 with a command like this:

PORT=80 node myapp.js

3)) The methods 1 and 2 are just for the development cases.
If you are using this for production, you should use the AWS service named ROUTE53.